# parsing an unknown tag xml file

Tags: python, sax

I was trying to parse an xml file.
My problem is same as this:

[parsing an xml file for unknown elements using python ElementTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817283/parsing-an-xml-file-for-unknown-elements-using-python-elementtree)

And I tried the solution of untubu.

It works great. But only for the lines which have single tags

For example:

```
   <some_root_name>
<tag_x>bubbles</tag_x>
 </some_root_name>
```

This works great
But if it is like:

```
src = '''\
<review type="review"><link>http://www.openlist.com/new-york-ny/mickey-mantles/27612417/?numReviews=178</link>
'''
```

it fails..
I have many instances like this.
I don't want to go beyond native libraries usage because after this I will run the code on different computer (prod env) and I will have to set the libraries there.. and it gets messy..

Is there a way , i can modify the original solution to solve this out.
Thanks.

The code from above link:

```
import xml.sax as sax
import xml.sax.handler as saxhandler
import pprint

class TagParser(saxhandler.ContentHandler):
    # http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.handler.html#contenthandler-objects
    def __init__(self):
        self.tags = {}
    def startElement(self, name, attrs):
        self.tag = name
    def endElement(self, name):
        if self.tag:
            self.tags[self.tag] = self.data
            self.tag = None
            self.data = None
    def characters(self, content):
        self.data = content

parser = TagParser()
src = '''\
<some_root_name>
    <tag_x>bubbles</tag_x>
    <tag_y>car</tag_y>
    <tag...>42</tag...>
</some_root_name>'''
sax.parseString(src, parser)
pprint.pprint(parser.tags)
```

Exception trace:

```
File "extract_xml.py", line 59, in unittest
  sax.parseString(src, parser)
File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\sax\__init__.py", line 49, in parseString
  parser.parse(inpsrc)
File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\sax\expatreader.py", line 107, in parse
  xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\sax\xmlreader.py", line 125, in parse
  self.close()
File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\sax\expatreader.py", line 217, in close
  self.feed("", isFinal = 1)
File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\sax\expatreader.py", line 211, in feed
  self._err_handler.fatalError(exc)
File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\sax\handler.py", line 38, in fatalError
  raise exception
xml.sax._exceptions.SAXParseException: <unknown>:2:4: no element found
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'it fails'? Any error message?

Comment: I ran your exact code in Python 2.7.2, and I got `{u'tag...': u'42', u'tag_x': u'bubbles', u'tag_y': u'car'}`.

Comment: Meanwhile, your problem description says that it works when the tags are on separate lines, but fails when they're all on the same line… and then your sample code shows it failing when the tags are on separate lines. Which is it?

Comment: @abarnert: oh.. I thought it failed if the multiple tags are on same line. I just edited the exact strign where it is failing
src = '''\
    <review type="review"><link>http://www.openlist.com/new-york-ny/mickey-mantles/27612417/?numReviews=178</link>
    '''

Comment: It sounds like you want to use `ElementTree`. The accepted answer to that question uses `ElementTree`, and seems to work for your data. (It uses `lxml.etree.ElementTree` instead of the built-in `xml.etree.ElementTree` or `xml.etree.cElementTree`, but that's literally a 1-character change.) So, why did you go to a different answer than the accepted one and switch to `xml.sax.handler`? Of course you can use `sax` if you want, but you don't have to.

Comment: The new `src` is a fragment that never closes the `review` tag, so of course it can't be parsed. If the `review` tag is closed later on, you need the whole tag. If it's never closed, you can't use any XML parser that requires valid XML; you might want to consider `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: @abarnert: The excepted answer uses lxml which is not a native library.. i have to install it seperately.. wheras xml comes native to python.. since iw ill run this code on different enviornment.. i want to use only native libs.

Comment: @Fraz: Did you actually read my comment before replying to it? "It uses `lxml.etree.ElementTree` instead of the built-in `xml.etree.ElementTree` or `xml.etree.cElementTree`, but that's literally a 1-character change."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TagParser` uses `endElement` to add data to `self.tags`.

With `src` equal to

```
src = '''\
<review type="review"><link>http://www.openlist.com/new-york-ny/mickey-mantles/27612417/?numReviews=178</link></review>
'''
```

The `<review>` has no closing tag, `</review>`, so `endElement` never gets called.

If you add a closing `</review>` tag to `src`:

```
src = '''\
<review type="review"><link>http://www.openlist.com/new-york-ny/mickey-mantles/27612417/?numReviews=178</link></review>
'''
```

then the program yields

```
{u'link': u'http://www.openlist.com/new-york-ny/mickey-mantles/27612417/?numReviews=178'}
```

Answer (score 1):

This actually works just fine, despite what your question says:

```
parser = TagParser()
src = '''\
<some_root_name>
    <tag_x>bubbles</tag_x>
    <tag_y>car</tag_y>
    <tag...>42</tag...>
</some_root_name>'''
sax.parseString(src, parser)
pprint.pprint(parser.tags)
```

`parser.tags` ends up as:

```
{u'tag...': u'42', u'tag_x': u'bubbles', u'tag_y': u'car'}
```

Your other example does fail, but only because it's not valid XML:

```
src = '''<review type="review"><link>http://www.openlist.com/new-york-ny/mickey-mantles/27612417/?numReviews=178</link>'''
parser = TagParser()
sax.parseString(src, parser)
pprint.pprint(parser.tags)
```

The `review` tag is never closed in your source, therefore this is not a valid XML fragment, therefore it raises an exception when you try to parse it.

If your problem is that you're taking incomplete fragments out of a valid document, don't do that; take the entire `review` tag and parse it, rather than trying to parse a single line out of it.

If your problem is that the source data is actually not valid XML, you need to use a parser designed to handle broken XML, like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/); neither `ElementTree` nor `xml.sax` is going to work.